Windows Powershell - How to start an unattended GUI session from EC2 SSM Powershell
Problem:
I need to launch an AWS EC2 Windows instance that needs to startup with a GUI with a gui program that is running before any user manual user interaction. My program must run in a UI session because it depends on 3rd party code which requires it. There is no option to run it from a GUI-less SSM session: The program needs to open actual windows and draw actual graphics in them...
Out of the box: EC2 windows provides you with RDP (Windows Remote Desktop) and SSM (Powershell) connectivity out of the box.
Partial Solution #1: I have configured it to start running after the user manually RDPs into the machine: I put an autostart batch file that fires when user logs in for the first time. The program and session stay active even after the RDP session is terminated. This is not good because it requires user interaction for the program to start. (user needs to manually RDP into the machine)
Partial Solution #2: Created an AWS-Lambda that RDPs into the Windows machine instead of the user. This is also sub-optimal because it creates a security hole: This windows machine contains user data, and we want to isolate it's VPC. (Not to mention we are storing private RDP passwords in the cloud! )
Looking for a way to set this up locally from within the EC2 machine's <userdata/> which runs in Windows powershell.
The main problem is that that said SSM powershell runs in a GUI-less admin state:
PS C:\Windows\system32> qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
 abcdee123456f...                        65536  Listen
 rdp-tcp                                 65537  Listen

Things I have tried so far:

Sysinternals PSEXEC and Autolgon

psexec /accepteula -d -s -i 2 RunMyGuiProgram.exe does work, but only after someone has manually logged in via RDP and created GuiSession2 by hand.
autologon Adminstrator $domain $password /accepteula only works when a GUI session is active (not from a GUI-less powershell)


Get the machine to RDP itself - cmdkey for setting passwords, does not work from non gui SSM session
WSL does not work from SSM (WSL version 1 once did, but even that does not work anymore)
Install python RDP client - requires vc redist that does not install properly on a non gui session (dead end for now)
DockerDesktop - Managed to install, but the docker daemon does not start from a non GUI session, and can't find a way to start it from non-gui powershell

